# why is my discord music bot not playing music

Tags: python, discord.py, spotify

Hey everyone about a week ago I started the project of making a discord music bot in python that plays playlists form Spotify with the goal being it to play a specific lofi playlist from Spotify unfortunately the bot doesn't work it joins the channel I am in but it wont play the playlist and it gives a error message in discord "The application did not respond" here is the part of the code that contains the Spotify part

```
@tree.command(name='play', description='play music', guild= guild_id)
async def play(interaction: discord.Interaction, playlist_uri: str):
    
    if interaction.guild.voice_client is not None:
        await interaction.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
    
    channel = interaction.user.voice.channel
    voice_client = await channel.connect()

    results = sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_uri)
    
    if results['item']:
        for item in results['items']:
            track = item['track']
            track_name = track['name']
            artist_name = track['artists'][0]['name']

            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Playing {track_name} by {artist_name}")

            track_url = track['external_urls']['spotify']

            ydl_opts = {
                'format': 'bestaudio/best',
                'postprocessors': [{
                    'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                    'preferredcodec':'mp3',
                    'preferredquality': '192',
                }],
            }
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                info = ydl.extract_info(track_url, download=False)
                url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']

            voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url2))
            while voice_client.is_playing():
                pass
            
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("No songs found on spotify")

@tree.command(name='pause', description='pause music', guild= guild_id)
async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    voice_client = interaction.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_connected():
        await voice_client.disconnect()
```

I asking multiple AI's but all the ai's can't solve the problem

I was expecting the bot to play the playlist I gave

Comment: Can you provide the error output?

Comment: Spotify Developer Policy - 
[III. Some prohibited applications](https://developer.spotify.com/policy#iii-some-prohibited-applications) - 
4. Do not create any product or service which includes any non-interactive internet webcasting service. For example, you can’t create an application which plays content from a single source to several simultaneous listeners.